# buildnumber-maven-plugin increments buildNumber twice

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I am new user of Maven, and am having difficulty getting the buildnumber-maven-plugin to do what I expect. Essentially, I want maven to build my project and create a JAR file of the result, and to set a build number in the manifest.mf file. I'll include most of my pom.xml file below.

When I run: mvn clean compile package, then I see two mentions of the buildNumber in the output:

```
...
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (buildnumber) @ xcase ---
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: 12 at timestamp: 1500583427060
...
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (buildnumber) @ xcase ---
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: 13 at timestamp: 1500583444250
...
```

and in my manifest file, I can see that the build is:

Implementation-Build: 13

If I run the mvn command again, then it is incremented to 15. Why is this?

Here is the relevant fragment of my pom.xml file:

```
  <build>
    <outputDirectory>build</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <buildNumberPropertyName>buildNumber</buildNumberPropertyName>
          <doCheck>false</doCheck>
          <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
          <format>{0,number,integer}</format>
          <items>
            <item>buildNumber</item>
          </items>
          <revisionOnScmFailure>true</revisionOnScmFailure>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
            <id>buildnumber</id>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <version>1.4</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/build</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>*local*.properties</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                  <includes>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                  </includes>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}/src/java</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                  <includes>
                    <include>log4j2.xml</include>
                  </includes>
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <sourceDirectory>src/java</sourceDirectory>
  </build>
```

Comment: Please add the full pom file and not only excerpts...furthermore don't change the conventions in Maven until you have understood the consequences. You configuration of maven-resources-plugin to copy things shows that you didn't understood the maven life cycle. If you follow conventions and put the resources into `src/main/resources` they will automatically be copied into `target/classes`. If you like to filter them see the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). Use most recent versions of plugins. The maven-jar-plugin is really ancient...

Comment: Hi - thanks, yes I know that the organization of resources is not as maven would like. I can't upload the full POM file because it has proprietary information in it. This is a project that is being built by an existing build system, so I won't be able to re-organize its directory structure until I'm able to demonstrate some of maven's cool capabilities. I've updated the maven-jar-plugin to 3.0.2. However, this hasn't solved the problem of incrementing the build number twice. Any ideas?